# While Loop to produce Mathematical Sequences?

Tags: python, while-loop

I've been asked to do the following:

Using a while loop, you will write a program which will produce the following                    mathematical sequence:

1 * 9 + 2 = 11(you will compute this number)

12 * 9 + 3 = 111

123 * 9 + 4 = 1111

Then your program should run as far as the results contain only "1"s. You can build your numbers as string, then convert to ints before calculation. Then you can convert the result back to a string to see if it contains all "1"s.

Sample Output:

1 * 9 + 2 = 11

12 * 9 + 3 = 111

123 * 9 + 4 = 1111

1234 * 9 + 5 = 11111

Here is my code:

```
def main():
    Current = 1
    Next = 2
    Addition = 2
    output = funcCalculation(Current, Addition)

    while (verifyAllOnes(output) == True):
           print(output)
           #string concat to get new current number
           Current = int(str(Current) + str(Next))
           Addition += 1
           Next += 1
           output = funcCalculation(Current, Next)

def funcCalculation(a,b):
    return (a * 9 + b)

def verifyAllOnes(val):
    Num_str = str(val)
    for ch in Num_str:
           if(str(ch)!= "1"):
               return False
    return True

main()
```

The bug is that the formula isn't printing next to the series of ones on each line. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: OK: the while loop has to terminate when the output doesn't match a sequence of 1s, so you probably want "whilst equation contains only 1s". Apart from that you'll need to add the next digit to x and increment z each iteration. Is that enough of a start, or is there anything more specific you'd need?

Answer (score 2):

Pseudo-code:

```
a = 1
b = 2    
result = a * 9 + b
while string representation of result contains only 1s:
    a = concat a with the old value of b, as a number
    b = b + 1
    result = a * 9 + b
```

This can be literally converted into Python code.

Comment: I guess I'm a little confused as to how you would tell Python to only look at the results where the numbers contain only ones.

Comment: @Kjc21793 Not sure what you mean? Which line do you have problems with?

Comment: while string representation of result contains only 1s:

confused as to how you would tell it to look for that

Comment: @Kjc21793 You can get a string representation of a number by using `str(yourNumber)`. You can iterate over a string using `for` giving you each character to check. As soon as you encounter something that isn’t `'1'` you know that there is something other than 1s.

Comment: But how can you use for when it's supposed to be a while loop? Didn't think you could do that

Comment: @Kjc21793: You can nest any kind of loop inside another kind.

Answer (score 1):

### Testing all ones

Well, for starters, here is one easy way to check that the value is all ones:

```
def only_ones(n):
    n_str = str(n)
    return set(n_str) == set(['1'])
```

You could do something more "mathy", but I'm not sure that it would be any faster. It would much more easily
generalize to other bases (than 10) if that's something you were interested in though

```
def only_ones(n):
    return (n % 10 == 1) and (n == 1 or only_ones2(n / 10))
```

### Uncertainty about how to generate the specific recurrence relation...

As for actually solving the problem though, it's actually not clear what the sequence should be.

What comes next?

```
123456
1234567
12345678
123456789
?
```

Is it 1234567890? Or 12345678910? Or 1234567900?
Without answering this, it's not possible to solve the problem in any general way (unless in fact the 111..s
terminate before you get to this issue).

I'm going to go with the most mathematically appealing assumption, which is that the value in question is the
sum of all the 11111... values before it (note that 12 = 11 + 1, 123 = 111 + 11 + 1, 1234 = 1111 + 111 + 11 + 1, etc...).

### A solution

In this case, you could do something along these lines:

```
def sequence_gen():
    a = 1
    b = 1
    i = 2
    while only_ones(b):
        yield b
        b = a*9 + i
        a += b
        i += 1
```

Notice that I've put this in a generator in order to make it easier to only grab as many results from this
sequence as you actually want. It's entirely possible that this is an infinite sequence, so actually running
the while code by itself might take a while ;-)

```
s = sequence_gen()
s.next() #=> 1
s.next() #=> 11
```

A generator gives you a lot of flexibility for things like this. For instance, you could grab the first 10 values of the sequence using the `itertools.islice`
function:

```
import itertools as it
s = sequence_gen()
xs = [x for x in it.islice(s, 10)]
print xs
```

Comment: The sequence is supposed to only contain ones

Comment: Yes, obviously the output sequence should contain only ones, and it will as returned from the generator. If you are referring to my question about "What comes next?", that is referring to what `x` is in your formulation of the equation (I used a for this, but in retrospect should have stuck with your notation for consistency...). Does that make sense? Or am I misinterpreting your comment?

Comment: I added some extra text which hopefully helps clarify the "What comes next?" question.